# How can I update an XML attribute node with the maximum of its sub-attributes?

Tags: xpath, xmlstarlet

Consider the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sportsClass>
    <pupils>
        <pupil name="Adam" highestJump="">
            <jump height="4"/>
            <jump height="1"/>
        </pupil>
        <pupil name="Berta" highestJump="">
            <jump height="4"/>
            <jump height="7"/>
        </pupil>
        <pupil name="Caesar" highestJump="">
            <jump height="1"/>
            <jump height="2"/>
        </pupil>
        <pupil name="Doris" highestJump="">
            <jump height="5"/>
            <jump height="5"/>
        </pupil>
    </pupils>
</sportsClass>
```

How can I fill the `highestJump` attribute nodes with the respective maximum `height` value, using xmlstarlet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem consists of two sub-problems:

## Finding the maximum

xmlstarlet does not have the `max()` function, so we have to find a way around:

```
cat jumps.xml | \
xmlstarlet select -t -v "//pupil/jump[not(@height <= following-sibling::jump/@height) and not(@height < preceding-sibling::jump/@height)]/@height"
```

Note the `<=` and `<` – if there are more than one maximum values, only the last one will be taken.

Result:

```
4
7
2
5
```

## Updating the attribute

### Constant value for practice

```
cat jumps.xml | xmlstarlet edit --update //pupil/@highestJump -v "Hahahaha"
```

...writes `Hahahaha` to every `highestJump` attribute.

### Simple XPath

Take care: The XPath you use for replacing

- is relative to the selected attribute (so `.` is *the attribute itself*)
- has to be wrapped with eg. `string()` to have an effect

So:

```
cat jumps.xml | xmlstarlet edit --update //pupil/@highestJump -x "string(../@name)"
```

...gives (shortened):

```
<pupil name="Adam" highestJump="Adam">
<pupil name="Berta" highestJump="Berta">
<pupil name="Caesar" highestJump="Caesar">
<pupil name="Doris" highestJump="Doris">
```

## Combining the two

```
cat jumps.xml | xmlstarlet edit --update //pupil/@highestJump -x "string(../jump[not(@height <= following-sibling::jump/@height) and not(@height < preceding-sibling::jump/@height)]/@height)"
```

...gives...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sportsClass>
  <pupils>
    <pupil name="Adam" highestJump="4">
      <jump height="4"/>
      <jump height="1"/>
    </pupil>
    <pupil name="Berta" highestJump="7">
      <jump height="4"/>
      <jump height="7"/>
    </pupil>
    <pupil name="Caesar" highestJump="2">
      <jump height="1"/>
      <jump height="2"/>
    </pupil>
    <pupil name="Doris" highestJump="5">
      <jump height="5"/>
      <jump height="5"/>
    </pupil>
  </pupils>
</sportsClass>
```